# How can I do "Version control" of a entire site in Liferay?

Tags: version-control, liferay

I am a member of a team who try to build several sites using Liferay. We have difficulty sharing updates between us using LAR files and we have the same problem building the test and QA version of the site. We like to use something like traditional version control where each one download a version of the site, do some changes and update the repository. Is there a way to do something like this? We suspect that we are using the LARs in the wrong way or maybe it is not meant to be used like this. Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Liferay site **only** files or not?!

Comment: No, it has one community with public and private pages, images and documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back up your database, check that in to your version control, The restore the database.

All the information required for a Liferay site is in the database (and the custom plugins if you're using them).

So I'd use backing up and restoring the database as your solution.

Comment: And the rest of the "data" directory, the images or document library can be recreated with only the database?

Comment: It depends on how you store Images and Documents. We use a JackRabbit database so we just backup our Liferay database, and our JackRabbit database and restore them both to another server. Usually Prod -> UAT -> Dev to make sure the data is in sync across all 3 environments.

Comment: For now, I do version control in the "data" directory and is working. Thanks

Comment: With this methode the Liferay enviroment must be completely identical. e.g. tomcat path.

Comment: @Mark Actually that's not entirely true. We use this approach across all 3 environments (4 if you count local) and the server names are all different. The important changes are all in the build.username.properties files.